# iOS5 button transparency with png image as background

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am running into some problems with one button that I am customizing for my app and I need some help with it. When I test the button with **iOS 6** there are no problems with the button transparency and the png image is viewed like this

[image]

but when i test my app with **iOS 5** the button is not transparent:

[image]

I have the following settings for the button:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions of how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you kept Button Type as UIButtonTypeCustom in UIButton Type property

Comment: but why this would help?